# Attaching gymastic rings / pull-up bar to the ceiling

Tags: garage

I am moving into a house, and planning to install some gym equipment in a garage. In particular, I want to add a pull up bar, made out of galvanized steel 1" pipes, and hang the gymnastic rings.

The ceilings are 11" and are dry-walled with the 1 5/8"x7" joists, spread 16" apart.

Most of the recommendations are to use eye-bolts or lag bolts. I am afraid that 1 5/8 joists are not wide/strong enough to hold the weight of the rings or the diy pull-up.

Comment: Do you have access to attic space above the ceiling?

Comment: I do. It is not a lot room to move around. I was considering pocking holes in the drywall, and just using the rings' straps over the joists, just as they were designed to be used. But that would not work for the pull up bar.

Answer (score 1):

You can always run 2x4 or 2x6 across the joists over the drywall where you want to suspend rings and the pull up bar. As long as you secure the board  properly across at least 2 joists (3.5” or 4” construction screws-2 or 3 per joist) you should be good. Not the prettiest setup, but it is quite strong and easy to mount to.

Comment: Just use smaller lag bolts? I am just not that confident that 1 5/8" joist will hold my weight.

Comment: @val lag bolts would be fine as well. As far as the joists supporting you, It supports your weight walking on it from above, so the wood can certainly handle that. Lag  screws can handle a great deal of weight. This might be helpful  https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/81543/how-can-i-choose-the-best-lag-screw-lag-bolt